# pouchdb db.login is not a function

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

Tried using these imports

```js
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
import PouchDBAuth from 'pouchdb-authentication';

PouchDB.plugin(PouchDBAuth)
```

Module ''pouchdb-authentication'' has no default export is the error generated while using these imports.

```js
PouchDB.plugin(require('pouchdb-authentication'));
```

Using require is removing the error but still showing db.login() is not a function. Can anyone suggest where the issue is?

Comment: maybe check the version of you plugin. your code should work; pouchdb-authentication definitely have a default export. and maybe do npm i again

Comment: Same here, I can output pouchdb-authentication which has the login function but this line does not affect the Pouchdb object : PouchDB.plugin(PouchDBAuth), so the db.login is undefined

Answer (score 3):

Well I found why it was not working in my situation, I was using this :

```
import '*' as PouchDBAuthentication from 'pouchdb-authentication';
```

instead of

```
import PouchDBAuthentication from 'pouchdb-authentication';
```

So the right way is

```
import PouchDBAuthentication from 'pouchdb-authentication';
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';

PouchDB.plugin(PouchDBAuthentication);
```

In the second hand the following steps should be done : 
https://github.com/pouchdb-community/pouchdb-authentication/issues/211

Answer (score 0):

No Need Below Library

```
import PouchAuth from 'pouchdb-authentication';
```

just pass auth
PouchDb

```
new PouchDB('url', {
  auth: {
    username: 'user',
    password: 'pass'
  }
}
```